# Deleting the array with splice not working properly?

Tags: angularjs

When i click on button value will be push to another array. next i click on the same button the pushing item will be deleted.
in my project pushing done  properly.but second time click on the same button first element in the array deleted not the selected one.

this is my html code.

```
<a  class="btn {{table.btnClass}} btn-success"  ng-click="getTable(table)" style="padding-left:1px">{{table.tablename}}</a>
```

This is my controller code

```
$scope.tableArray=[]
$scope.tableslist=[]
$scope.getTable=function(table){
    table.btnClass = table.btnClass == "btn-danger" ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger"
    console.log(table)
    var exists=false;
    angular.forEach($scope.tableArray, function (list) {
        if ((list.tablename == table.tablename)) {
            console.log(list.tablename)
             console.log(table.tablename)
            exists=true;
            $scope.tableArray.splice(list._id,1)
            return false
        }
     });
  if(!exists){
  $scope.tableslist.push(table)
  $scope.tableArray=$scope.tableslist
  console.log($scope.tableArray)
   table.color="red"
    }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a second argument in foreach, use index to splice from array

```
 angular.forEach($scope.tableArray, function (list, index) {
    ----------
    -------------------
    $scope.tableArray.splice(index,1)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

For delete the selected item in an array you can use the indexOf as I mentioned below.

```
  $scope.tableArray.splice($scope.tableArray.indexOf(list),1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across the similar problem with Splice. In my case, I had to resolve as below just incase if it helps someone.

If you are dealing with objects, please note indexOf works for array not for an Object inside that array. You can do something like below to identify the index and handle this case;

```
$scope.removeReport = function(report) {
    var index = $scope.contact.reports.map(function(r) { return r.id;}).indexOf(report.id);
        if (index >= 0) {
          $scope.contact.reports.splice(index, 1);
        }
}
```